# How to run a slightly different version of a test class in xunit

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I am integration-testing a ASP.NET Core API application, where clients can access the same resource in two different routes (for backward compatibility reasons).

I have a test class with around 40 tests.

How can I run the test two times, one with route A and one with route B? Like a `[Theory]` but at the class level.

My alternative is to decorate each method with:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("/routeA")]
[InlineData("/routeB")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the class abstract, then add 2 concrete classes derived from it is a common pattern (that, or add a new class derived from it; the base class tests will be run for it too, but typically you'll have an abstract member that can induce the variance you seek)

Answer (score 0):

Use `MemeberData` or `ClassData`.
See this [example](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/HamidMosalla/54058b60b0a30c86a6537f200be2a354/raw/635cd5e33fe6b9ba5520d9a6a46743f42c712663/TheoryWithMemberData.cs) from this [article](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/).